# Is it possible to get a permit to travel to Tibet (Lhasa) from Beijing by train, without a tour guide?

Tags: china, trains, permits, tibet

I am confused about how I go about getting a permit for two people (a British and a Swedish national) to visit Lhasa, intending to travel there by train. Is it possible to get a permit without having to have a tour guide? I don't mind going through an agency.

Comment: There is a train from Beijing to Lhasa, you can just buy a ticket and go there, of course, if you have visa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far as I'm aware, it isn't currently possible. [You can hire guides individually though](http://www.tour-beijing.com/lhasa_tour/#4).

I've heard from a couple of different people that permits to Tibet for foreigners are currently closed though, so you'd probably do just as well to call an agency (the big places all have English speaking staff as well) and see what the say. It's hard to find concrete information on these kinds of things, but the agencies are usually more up to date.

Hope that helps. Good luck with your travels.

Answer (score 8):

No independent travel in Tibet since March 2008, and near impossible before that. Tibet has been closed in March every year since 2008 (preventing protests around March 10th , the failed rebellion and escape of Dalai Lama in -59)  , and is closing as we speak .

Best way in is by train , esp. if you break up the journey one or two nights in Xining ( altitude 2300-ish). Use the extra [oxygen outlets](http://korta.nu/3e3c) the first hours after Golmud

Lots of Tibetan culture outside Lhasa and the dotted line of TAR if permits won't appear - see [here](http://kekexili.typepad.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the permit without a guide, but you must be accompanied by a guide in the Tibetan area -- the government doesn't allow solo foreign travelers.

Now it's easier to get Tibet Travel Permit for foreigners.
Since this year, The government didn't close Tibet, it's a symbol that it's easier go get into Tibet.
But, you still must though the agency to get the TTP.

Comment: er...maybe I didn't state clearly.

Comment: but, what i want to tell is couldn't going anywhere without a guide. The government prohibit foreigners solo traveler in Tibet.

Comment: I edited your post to clear up the first line and incorporate your comments. However you should edit the second line if you have some new information (i.e. *why* is it easier for foreigners to get the travel permit, since when).

Comment: Sure, your  Majesty.